# Returning Image (LONGBLOB) from Custom WordPress DB Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to return an image from my database. The image is a `.jpg` and is `19kb`. The image is also being saved in the DB as a `.bin`, I'm guessing this is correct? When returning the image from the DB I am met with a slew of odd characters `��z�Q�yi�j�ȗ�����<` that's just a small portion.

I've tried setting the headers `header('Content-type: image/jpeg')` and I just receive a `Cannot change headers...` error from WordPress. Any ideas?

### Query DB and return information

```
  public static function output_lyrics($atts) {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix.'bb_hello_dolly';
    $sql        = "SELECT
                   text, pic
                   FROM
                   $table_name;";
    $result     = $wpdb->get_results($sql, 'ARRAY_A');

    if ($result) {
      $san_lyrics = explode("\n", sanitize_textarea_field( $result[0]['text'] ) );

      header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
      echo '<img src="'.$result[0]['pic'].'">';
      return $san_lyrics[ rand(0, count($san_lyrics) - 1 ) ];
    } else {
        echo 'Whoops, I think I forgot the lyrics...';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, storing images in your database is a really bad idea, and will balloon the size of your database quickly, and negatively impact performance. It's a much better idea to create a randomized filename and store the image in a folder on the server, then reference the filename in the database.

That said, assuming you have no control over the database storage, the reason you're having trouble setting the headers is that you are trying to mix your image with content on the same page request, and you can't change headers mid-stream. Setting headers will only work if you have a separate script set up that does nothing but grab the image from the DB and render it, with no other content. Then you would simply make the url to that script (with whatever query parameters are necessary to grab the correct image) the content of the src attribute of a standard image tag.

Alternatively, you could take the big blob of image data that you received from the DB, base64 encode it, add the prefix `data:image/jpeg;base64,`, and put it as the src attribute of an img tag.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and the explanations. I guess I'll go for your first suggestion. This is a plugin I'm trying creating so I'll see what I can do about uploading it to the Media Library. Thanks!